# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 using mvn - v

Tags: java, maven

I trying to run Maven 3.0.4 with java 6. Below is my bash profile and attached screenshots to validate location:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME


M2_HOME=/Users/bchart545/apache-maven-3.0.4
export M2_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin

export PATH
```

[image]
[image]
I've tried both:
[Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052428/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0) and 
[mvn -v gives me "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42902472/mvn-v-gives-me-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

Not seeing what I'm missing, I want it to run with Java 6. 
Thanks and sorry for the new post.

Comment: Show us the full stacktrace.

Comment: Are you sure you have `[![JAVA_HOME=...` and not `JAVA_HOME=...`? Run the command `set -x` and then in the same command line window `mvn -v` and post the output.

Comment: COSML-1718672:~ bchart545$ mvn -v
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/launcher/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)

Comment: Hi @KarolDowbecki, my bash profile is exactly as above in comment, it was a typo in my post. Still getting error. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Use `set -x` to see what exactly `mvn` is executing, it's just another script. It could be that you have another `JAVA_HOME` definition but you won't know until you debug `mvn` script.

Comment: I'm sorry @KarolDowbecki, what is `set -x` and where do I use it?

Comment: Remove the `M2_HOME` and only add the path to the `bin` directory of Maven to your path...Apart from that please use more recent version of Maven (or at least Maven 3.0.5) ...why do you need Java 6 ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Ok, i'll try that. We need Java 6 cause this app is a VERY legacy app. Looking to get it run locally.

Comment: You can use most recent Maven version and use toolchain to compile/run tests with older JDK version...

Comment: @khmarbaise Commented out the `#M2_HOME=/Users/bchart545/apache-maven-3.0.5` and set `PATH=$PATH:/Users/bchart545/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin` and upgraded maved to 3.0.5. Still getting error. It's definitely a java version issue, I upgraded to java 8 and it worked. Java 6 does not like maven 3.0.5.

Comment: @Billy I bet there is another problem then JDK 6 <-> Maven 3.0.5 (minimum is here JDK 5)... apart from that do you really need to work on JDK 6 or just produce JDK 6 compatible code? you could use `<target>6</target>` even with JDK 8+...

Comment: I have the `maven-compiler-plugin` with `<target>1.6</target>`, just produce 1.6 compatible jar.

Comment: @khmarbaise my co-workers have it working with 3.0.4 maven and java 1.6.0_45, I have 1.6.0_65 jave and maven 3.0.4. Only difference is that I'm on a mac and they're PC. Any anything that would conflict there perhaps?

Comment: What would help would be full logging output of the maven build .....

Comment: @khmarbaise This is the entire output:

`COSML-1718672:Desktop bchart545$ mvn -v
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/launcher/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)`

 Can I enable more detailed logging for this command?

Comment: I bet you have set a M2_HOME/MAVEN_HOME variable in your environment? (`printenv | grep -i "^M"`)...cause the version 51 is a class which needs Java 7...and the classworlds part is the bootstrap part of Maven itself...Have you set JAVA_HOME?

Comment: @khmarbaise yep, `JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home` and `M2_HOME=/Users/bchart545/apache-maven-3.0.4`. It's clearly a version issue, but it works for my co-workers which is the most confusing thing to me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the only thing that I can think of that I did was go into /usr/local/Cellar/ and delete the maven folder (for the second time) and now it seems to work. Below is my bash_profile:

```
#set JAVA_HOME
#JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
#JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
#JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME


M2_HOME=/Users/bchart545/apache-maven-3.0.4
export M2_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin

export PATH
```